# Compare data from two arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, compare

I am currently struggling to compare two arrays.

The first array ($allRoepnummerArray) contains all the callnumbers available.

The second array ($occupiedRoepnummers) contains the call numbers that are occupied.

At the moment I am unable to compare them.

I would like to have the available call numbers in a table.

```
$allRoepnummerArray = array(
                                '22-101',
                                '22-102',
                                '22-103',
                                '22-104',
                                '22-105',
                                '22-106',
                                '22-107',
                                '22-108',
                                '22-109',
                                '22-110',
                                '22-111',
                                '22-112',
                                '22-113',
                                '22-114',
                                '22-115',
                                '22-116',
                                '22-117',
                                '22-118',
                                '22-119',
                                '22-120',
                                '22-121',
                                '22-122',
                                '22-123',
                                '22-124',
                                '22-125',
                                '22-126',
                                '22-127',
                                '22-128',
                                '22-129',
                                '22-130',
                            );

                            $occupiedRoepnummers = array();

                            foreach ($roepnummerResults as $roepnummerKey => $roepnummerValue) {
                                array_push($occupiedRoepnummers, $roepnummerValue['roepnummer']);
                            }

                            foreach($allRoepnummerArray as $allRoepnummer) {
                                foreach($occupiedRoepnummers as $occupiedRoepnummer) {

                                    if ($allRoepnummer != $occupiedRoepnummer) {
                                        echo '<th>'.$allRoepnummer.'</th>';
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                            ?>
```

Comment: What's the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subtract arrays with [array_diff()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php). In your case you could do:

```
$availableRoepnummers = array_diff($allRoepnummerArray, $occupiedRoepnummers);
```

You can then make a HTML table of the `$availableRoepnummers`.

Comment: Thank you! I tried that before but it didn't worked out. But thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
foreach($allRoepnummerArray as $allRoepnummer) {
if (!in_array($allRoepnummer,$occupiedRoepnummers)) {
                                    echo '<th>'.$allRoepnummer.'</th>';
                                }}
```

Comment: @max check my answer now just copy it and it will work

Answer (score 0):

use array_intersect() function like below it will retrun only matched values

```
$a1=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue","d"=>"yellow");
$a2=array("e"=>"red","f"=>"black","g"=>"purple");
$a3=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"black","h"=>"yellow");

$result= array_intersect($a1,$a2);
print_r(array_diff($a1,$result));
```

result : `Array ( [b] => green [c] => blue [d] => yellow )`

Comment: I need tot non matched values.